# Elsevier citation containing Author, Year (solved)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, elsarticle

after the review process at an Elsevier journal, I was told the reference format is wrong. I looked it up and it appears, that in the text when you cite they would like to have `(Name, year)`, whereas I get `(Name (year))`.

As of now my text looks like this:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fB}{f_\mathrm{B}}
\newcommand{\Trca}{T_\mathrm{RCA}}
\newcommand{\Dh}{D_\mathrm{h}}
\newcommand{\fpeak}{f_\mathrm{peak}}
\newcommand{\degC}{^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}
\newcommand{\red}{\textcolor{red}}
%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{square,sort,comma,numbers}
%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
```

They provide different `\bibliographystyle`s, but none of them is correct. I have been spending days on the internet trying things and I thought, I could maybe get a nice answer here.

I read all the previous discussions about this, but none changed what I needed.

EDIT: I cite using

```
(\cite{Engstrom2013a})
```

and in the b`enter code here`ib file it looks like this:

```
@article{Engstrom2013a,
abstract = {Control of the global epidemic tuberculosis is severely hampered by the emergence of drug-resistant Mycobacterium tuberculosis strains. Molecular methods offer a more rapid means of characterizing resistant strains than phenotypic drug susceptibility testing. We have developed a molecular method for detection of rifampicin-resistant M. tuberculosis based on padlock probes and magnetic nanobeads. Padlock probes were designed to target the most common mutations associated with rifampicin resistance in M. tuberculosis, i.e. at codons 516, 526 and 531 in the gene rpoB. For detection of the wild type sequence at all three codons simultaneously, a padlock probe and two gap-fill oligonucleotides were used in a novel assay configuration, requiring three ligation events for circularization. The assay also includes a probe for identification of the M. tuberculosis complex. Circularized probes were amplified by rolling circle amplification. Amplification products were coupled to oligonucleotide-conjugated magnetic nanobeads and detected by measuring the frequency-dependent magnetic response of the beads using a portable AC susceptometer.},
author = {Engstr{\"{o}}m, Anna and {Zard{\'{a}}n G{\'{o}}mez de la Torre}, Teresa and Str{\o}mme, Maria and Nilsson, Mats and Herthnek, David},
doi = {10.1371/journal.pone.0062015},
isbn = {1932-6203},
issn = {19326203},
journal = {PLoS ONE},
number = {4},
pages = {e62015},
pmid = {23630621},
title = {{Detection of Rifampicin Resistance in Mycobacterium tuberculosis by Padlock Probes and Magnetic Nanobead-Based Readout}},
volume = {8},
year = {2013}
}
```

Comment: are you using the template provided by said journal?

Comment: yes, since elsevier has quite a lot of journals they provide a general one with many different possibilities (which are shown in the text).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I have only `\bibliographystyle{model5-names}` installed on my system (so please check the available bibliography styles by your own for the needed display of informations they want -- **or better ask them which bibliography style you should use -- they should know best!**), but the real culprit in your case is that you have to use command

```
\citep{Engstrom2013a}
```

to get the result they want (please see the `p` at the end of `\citep`).

With the following complete mwe

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Engstrom2013a,
abstract = {Control of the global epidemic tuberculosis is severely hampered by the emergence of drug-resistant Mycobacterium tuberculosis strains. Molecular methods offer a more rapid means of characterizing resistant strains than phenotypic drug susceptibility testing. We have developed a molecular method for detection of rifampicin-resistant M. tuberculosis based on padlock probes and magnetic nanobeads. Padlock probes were designed to target the most common mutations associated with rifampicin resistance in M. tuberculosis, i.e. at codons 516, 526 and 531 in the gene rpoB. For detection of the wild type sequence at all three codons simultaneously, a padlock probe and two gap-fill oligonucleotides were used in a novel assay configuration, requiring three ligation events for circularization. The assay also includes a probe for identification of the M. tuberculosis complex. Circularized probes were amplified by rolling circle amplification. Amplification products were coupled to oligonucleotide-conjugated magnetic nanobeads and detected by measuring the frequency-dependent magnetic response of the beads using a portable AC susceptometer.},
author = {Engstr{\"{o}}m, Anna and {Zard{\'{a}}n G{\'{o}}mez de la Torre}, Teresa and Str{\o}mme, Maria and Nilsson, Mats and Herthnek, David},
doi = {10.1371/journal.pone.0062015},
isbn = {1932-6203},
issn = {19326203},
journal = {PLoS ONE},
number = {4},
pages = {e62015},
pmid = {23630621},
title = {{Detection of Rifampicin Resistance in Mycobacterium tuberculosis by Padlock Probes and Magnetic Nanobead-Based Readout}},
volume = {8},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fB}{f_\mathrm{B}}
\newcommand{\Trca}{T_\mathrm{RCA}}
\newcommand{\Dh}{D_\mathrm{h}}
\newcommand{\fpeak}{f_\mathrm{peak}}
\newcommand{\degC}{^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}
\newcommand{\red}{\textcolor{red}}
%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{square,sort,comma,numbers}
%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
\cite{Engstrom2013a}

\citet{Engstrom2013a}

\citep{Engstrom2013a} % <===============================================

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you so much!! this solved the citation problem. 
I have edited the question regarding the reference part because I noticed something I had not seen before. The journal doesnt asnwer to my request of knowing what to use..